# Excel VBA - Make multiple fields required based on value of another field

Tags: excel, vba

I've created a request form in Excel with VB which uses a submit button to generate an email in outlook based on the values entered into the form.

Everything works fine. However, users often fail to complete all the necessary fields before submitting the request.

I need to be sure the user completes all the required fields when a specific value is entered into cell D7 before they submit the request

Here is where I get lost...I've tried approaching it two slightly different ways.

Hopefully someone can help me with this!

Approach 1:

When the submit button is pressed...

```
Button_click()

If Range("D7").Value = "Special Request" THEN
'Make cells B6, B7, B8, B9, D14 mandatory in order to generate email 

    On Error Resume Next
    If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Request").Range _
    ("B6, B7, B8, B9, D14 ") Is Nothing Then

    MsgBox ("Please confirm all required fields have been completed!")

'Do not generate email
```

---

Approach 2:

When the submit button is pressed...

```
Button_click()


'If the value of cell D7 is ANYTHING OTHER THAN "Special Feature", 
'execute code as normal to generate email

'Else, check for empty fields in the required cells ("B6, B7, B8, B9, D14 ") 

'if any required cells are empty, display message and do not generate email    
MsgBox ("Please confirm all required fields have been completed!")   

'If D7 = "Special Feature" AND NO REQUIRED FIELDS ARE MISSING, 
'continue with executing code to     generate email
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to go about it:

```
    Sub test()
If Range("D7").Value = "Special Request" And _
    Range("B6").Value = "" Or _
    Range("B7").Value = ""  Or _
    Range("B8").Value = "" Or _
    Range("B9").Value = "" Or _
    Range("D14").Value = "" Then
        MsgBox ("Please confirm all required fields have been completed!")
        Exit Sub
Else
        ' whatever method you're using to generate email goes here

End If



End Sub
```

Here is another way using CountA:

```
Sub test2()

If Range("D7").Value = "Special Request" And _ 
Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("B6:B9"), Range("D14")) < 5 Then
        MsgBox ("Please confirm all required fields have been completed!")
        Exit Sub
Else
        ' whatever method you're using to generate email goes here

End If


End Sub
```

Comment: I think those should be `OR`s between the ranges in #1. For #2, shouldn't it be `<5`?

Comment: +1 for number 2, which I think is the way to go. On #1, I'd do one more thing - put parentheses around the `ORs`. I'm not sure that it will work without them, and at any rate, they'd clarify the conditions.

Comment: For what it's worth, on my mock up, #1 works w/o any parentheses.  I prefer #2 as well, but it's nice to have options I guess.  There are some benefits to #1, like you can specify various conditions for each field if the business needs change without having to do a bunch of rework, albeit not as efficient if you get too crazy with a slew of mandatory fields where the only requirement is "can't be blank".

Comment: Awesome! Went with the first method and it works like a charm. Thanks for all the input! Greatly appreciated!